# Material-UI + TypeScript (No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ClassNameMap<"container" | "navBar" | "section0">'.)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Currently my project creates a TS Error "(No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ClassNameMap<"container" | "navBar" | "section0">'.)"

I have the following code to map out some divs:

```
<ReactFullpage.Wrapper>
    {[<Hero />, <About />, <Releases />].map((c, i) => (
         <div key={`section-${i}`} className={`section ${classes['section'+ i]}`}>
             {c}
         </div>
     ))}
</ReactFullpage.Wrapper>
```

The following code is currently being used to quickly create some Material CSS:

```
const useStyle = makeStyles({
  container: {
    height: '100vh',
    paddingTop: '64px',
    border: 'solid red 1px'
  },
  navBar: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  },
  'section0': {
    background: 'black'
  },
  'section1': {
    background: 'red'
  },
  'section2': {
    background: 'blue'
  },
})
```

What would be the quickest way to extend the ClassNameMap type to allow for mapped styles? I can see the Props is automatically updating in the background with "container" | "navBar" | "section0". I am not sure how I can extend this type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can the answer below solve your problem? If yes, please accept the answer. If no, please provide more details for us.

Comment: That works thanks, I went with your second solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to get rid of the type error.

**01 way:**

Make the return type of `useStyle` to be `Record<string, string>` instead of  `Record<"container" | "navBar" | "section0" | "section1" | "section2", string>`

- `Recode<string, string>` means it can accept any key as value, so the dynamic `section + runtime number` can be used without error

```
import { Theme, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyle = makeStyles<Theme>({ // put Theme in generic definition will make it to use object - Record<string, string> as default behind the scene
  ...
})
```

**02 way:**

Keep the useStyle return type and cast the dynamic `section + runtime number` be one of the sections key to tell typescript the dynamic key must be "section0"/"section1"/"section2" explicitly.

```
...
<div
    key={`section-${i}`}
    className={`section ${
        classes[("section" + i) as "section0" | "section1" | "section2"]
    }`}
>
   {c}
</div>
...
```

Here is the codesandbox for your reference.

- Demo1.tsx is the 01 way
- Demo2.tsx is the 02 way

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-chandrasekhar-hmlr7?file=/src/Demo2.tsx:763-961